# How do I change this show/hide DIV code?

Tags: php, html, hide, show

I am using this show/hide DIV code in my project: http://papermashup.com/demos/jquery-show-hide-plugin/

Currently, after you click VIEW, the div appears and the words VIEW become CLOSE, which you then hit to close the div. Is there anyway we could move the CLOSE so that it comes up inside the DIV that appears?

I'm new at this and I've been trying all night and I can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the append() function you can insert code into a certain div.
Try something like

```
$("#slidingDiv_2").append("<a href='#' class='show_hide' rel='#slidingDiv_2'>Close</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to leave that `showHide.js` alone, there is a simple solution.

1) Create the "Close" text in the div that appears

2) Give it the property so that when clicked, it executes a `.slideUp()` function that accomplishes the exact same thing as the other "Close" text in the sample page.

[`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)